# Ember.js: Get the HTML result of evaluating an EmberJs.Handlebars template

Tags: html, ember.js, handlebars.js

Something I've been looking for some time now, is how to get the HTML when evaluating a template.

In Handlebars this is very strait forward:

```
var source   = $("#entry-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var context = {title: "My New Post", body: "This is my first post!"}
var html    = template(context);
```

But, with Ember, things are different, and I'm wondering how this can be achieved. For now, I only can think of:

```
var template = App.MyView.create() ;
var html = template.??????????
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What do you want to achieve in the end?

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nwne8/7/) is an jsfiddle which shows what I need to do. The problem, I think, is that the name of the view is stored in a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
var view = App.MyView.create();
var $elem;
Ember.run(function() {
    $elem = $('<div>');
    view.appendTo($elem);
});
var html = $elem.html();
```

Comment: I can't get it to work. Somehow it returns an empty string. Furthermore, how do I pass it a context ? [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nwne8/7/) is a jsfiddle in which I've implemented your solution!

Comment: I believe that's because the append wasn't actually happening right away. I've edited the answer to show how to get the append to happen right away.

Comment: nice, it works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nwne8/8/)! The only thing that I can't get to work is the contentBinding. How to do that in this situation ?

Comment: I've updated [the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nwne8/9/) so that the `msg` parts show up. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: thnx, thats what I needed!! But somehow, your solution does feel like a hack :)

Comment: I agree. Ember is definitely not intended to be used this way. The original question asked how to get the html from an `Ember.View`, so I answered within that context. I've [updated the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nwne8/10/) with a somewhat less hackish way to accomplish what is laid-out in your original jsFiddle.

Comment: very nice solution. Thats indeed much better! thnx again!

Comment: This solution is not working for me, and it appears to be due to newer versions of ember, judging by the age of this question, and the error message I get: `EmberError: Container was not found when looking up a views template. This is most likely due to manually instantiating an Ember.View. See: http://git.io/EKPpnA`. Any ideas on an updated solution?

Answer (score 1):

Things appear to have changed a bit since the original answer, creating a view without a parent container is no longer supported in Ember (see https://gist.github.com/stefanpenner/5627411), and will throw an error: `Using the defaultContainer is no longer supported. [defaultContainer#lookup]`.

To fix this, there are two options:
`this.createChildView(viewClass, viewAttributes)`
OR
`this.container.lookup('view:view-class')` then setting the attributes on the view.

Of the two, `createChildView` is the easiest to implement and better practice.

With this in mind, Ben's answer would look more like:

```
var view = this.createChildView(App.MyView);
var $elem;
Ember.run(function() {
    $elem = $('<div>');
    view.appendTo($elem);
});
var html = $elem.html();
```